# Preventing buffer corruption of inputted array of char

Tags: c, arrays, corruption

I want to ask how to prevent a corruption in the array buffer, This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define buffSize 20

void clrscr() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; ++i)
        putchar('\n');
}

int main() {
    char arr1[buffSize];
    char arr2[buffSize];

    do {
        clrscr();

        printf("String 1 :\n");
        scanf("%[^\n]", &arr1); fflush(stdin);//prompt first string
    } while(strlen(arr1) > buffSize);

    do {
        clrscr();

        printf("String 1: %s\n\n", arr1);//The problem is here
        printf("String 2 : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]", &arr2); fflush(stdin);
    } while(strlen(arr2) > buffSize);

    return 0;
}
```

Say that we have inputted the first arr of char correspondingly to the buffSize, then we input the second arr of char which has inputs that exceeds the limitation of the buffSize. The arr1 will be assigned with some of the characters that was inputted above the arr2 size. How to prevent this ?

Comment: There are reasons new C users are encouraged to use `fgets` over `scanf` for user input. Here `fgets (arr1, sizeof arr1, stdin);` (and the same for `arr2`). However, just as with `scanf`, you need to insure that there are no characters left unread in `stdin` (e.g. you enter 50 chars, but have arrays sized for `19` + the nul-terminating character. Your immediate problem is the `"&"` sign before `&arr1` and `&arr2` (they are already pointers, you don't need to take the address of the pointer for `scanf`)

Answer (score 3):

`fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, it is generally only defined for output streams.

Try this instead :

```
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

If you are trying to limit the number of characters that `scanf()` attempts to read, you can use :

```
scanf("%19[^\n]", arr2);
```

Note that the number specified in `scanf()` must be one less than your buffer size to save room for `'\0'` and it should be `arr1` and `arr2`, no `&`.  Array names are already pointers to the beginning of the array.

Comment: generally only **used** -> only **defined**, something like *The `fflush()` function only has defined behavior for output streams, since `stdin` is an input stream then the behavior of `fflush(stdin)` is undefined. Although in practice, it's implementation defined, according to the standard it's behavior is not defined.*

Comment: Quibble, "generally only defined for *seekable* streams" ... which is where the ambiguity comes from, but other than the linguistic quibble -- you are both correct `;)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Ok, now I am about to learn a new and surely useful word. Quibble!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It is indded a very useful word that I wish I knew before, in my language *Sutileza*.

Comment: That's a highly technical term, but synonymous with "nit pic".

Comment: Code that does not check the return value of `scanf("%19[^\n]", arr2);` is weak.  Add a check.  Also `scanf("%19[^\n]", arr2);` does not well handle a line that begins with `'\n'`.  Better tot use `fgets()`.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi We both learned new words tonight, and I sheepishly have to admit, I didn't know "Sutileza". Now I have to go figure out from what base it is derived. I bet my brother knew that one. He spent a few years in Porto.

Comment: Thanks all for the information, I really appreciate it !!

Comment: I wonder why we can use fgets(); syntax to get a string for command prompt line, as far as I know it is a syntax to get a string from a file, even though in this case I am not using a file for IO any data. Any explanation for this ?